# Stack Oveflow beta app crashes on startup when trying to log-in in iOS 8.3 beta

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The StackOveflow beta app crashes (in an iPhone 6 device) when trying to log-in in iOS 8.3 beta 1.

I am using the bet app, v1.1.2.195

The crash occurs when using the Facebook login option.
I did not try with other login options as I do not use those.

The only way to "restore" the app is to re-install it (but not login, as it would start crashing on startup again).

Comment: Is no one experiencing this?

Comment: Could we have a screenshot? Any error?

Comment: Nope. It crashes right after the splash screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is working again in 8.3 beta 2...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like iOS 8.3β1 did not package HelveticaNeue-Light correctly and the app crashed when we failed to cache the `nil` font.  Seeing as [this is not the first time something like this has happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527962/what-happened-to-helveticaneue-italic-on-ios-7-0-3/19691404#19691404), I've gone ahead and added a fallback so our app will use a the system recommended font when that happens.